# In JPA, is there a way to prevent an object from being instantiated more than once?

Tags: java, jpa

If I have an instance of a class like Account it might be desirable to prevent an instance corresponding to one user's account from being instantiated simultaneously more than once. Is this possible using JPA?

To clarify as suggested by Edwin: In a system there are multiple Accounts. When someone logs in, we would probably instantiate that person's Account in order to determine what privileges that person has. What if a system admin wanted to access that same Account, perhaps changing the privileges while the owner of the Account is still using it? Is there a way to prevent this or is there a way to notify the system admin that the Account has been instantiated?

Comment: Your problem should not be solved by preventing instantiation of the entity. This is a classical problem of mutual exclusion. You need to ensure that only one person at the time can use the entity, and for that matter you need some form of locking. You can either use a flag/version field in the entity itself or consider JPA mechanisms for locking. See section 3.4 Locking and Concurrency in the JPA Specification.

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanted to allow the user to change his Account at the same time the sys admin was doing so, I assume Locking and Concurrency would offer a mechanism to deal with this also?

Comment: That's pretty much the idea of idea of [mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and [concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. The way JPA implementations work already guarantee that when you ask for an entity to your entity manager during a given a transaction, you will always get the  same entity.

So, entities are tied to the existence of their context and in JPA there are different types of contexts.

See the [JPA 2.1 Specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) chapter 7 on Entity Managers and Persistence Contexts.

Now, this will not prevent anyone from creating instances of your class and use them as they see fit. Or that you have detached entities in your application. For example, prior to you persisting a new entity, it is detached and not under the control of the entity manager.

You may consider reading section 3.2 Entity Instance Life Cycle in the same specification mentioned above.

So, perhaps you should tell us what you want to do and we could help with ideas of how to do it. Instead of giving us what you think is the answer. Start with a description of what you think is the problem that you believe you could solve if you could prevent JPA from providing multiple/different instances of a given entity.

Comment: As you suggest, here is the problem as I see it: In a system there are multiple Accounts. When someone logs in, we would probably instantiate that person's Account in order to determine what privileges that person has. What if a system admin wanted to access that same Account, perhaps changing the privileges while the owner of the Account is still using it? Is there a way to prevent this or is there a way to notify the system admin that the Account has been instantiated?

Comment: @Jeff You should probably add this comment to your question, under an "Edit" header so that everyone knows this is what you'd like to know.

Comment: Edwin, just to clarify my thinking on this, I could imagine how somehow JPA would allow you to specify that you wanted either a warning before instantiating an object that was already in memory or even prevent the operation. Is that not a reasonable functionality to expect or want?

Comment: @Jeff Well, without judging the effectiveness of that approach, there is an annotation that could work for that named `@PostLoad`. You can annotate a method in your entity with that annotation and its code gets triggered when the entity is loaded. You can count how many times it has been loaded perhaps using a static field. You will probably have to deal with certain level of synchronization to make it work that way, though. The problem is how do you know if the load happened by your own user or some other one, or when to reset the field.